# $T\in\mathcal K(H)$ , $(e_n)$ orthonormal sequence. Prove $Te_n \rightarrow 0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T:H\to H$ a compact operator. Let $(e_n)$ be an orthonormal sequence in H.
>
> Prove $Te_n \rightarrow 0$.

Hint: what do you know about $\langle Te_n,f\rangle$ for $f\in H$?

I'm taking a course in Hilbert space and operators and stumbled on this problem that I can't see how to solve.

Can somebody please help me solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint tells you to note that $\langle Te_n,f\rangle \to 0$, as
$$
\langle Te_n,f\rangle=\langle e_n,T^*f\rangle\to 0
$$
since $e_n$ converges to $0$ weakly. So $Te_n$ converges to $0$ weakly.

Now for the sake of contradiction, suppose it does not converge strongly to $0$, then along a subsequence
$$
\lim_{n'\to \infty}\|Te_{n'}\|>\delta>0.
$$
But then by compactness, there is a further subsequence such that $Te_{n''}\to g$ for some $g$ strongly. But $\|g\|>\delta$ by the above, while we still have $Te_{n''}$ converges weakly to $0$, contradicting that weak and strong limits should agree.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain why $<e_n,y>\rightarrow 0$. $(e_n)$ is not a base for H so I don't think it is true for all $y\in H$

Comment: It's an orthonormal sequence, these always converge to 0 weakly. Think Bessel's inequality (rather than Parseval's identity, which is probably what you have in mind when $e_n$ is a basis)

Comment: Thank you very much :), very nice solution. On a side, note the transition $<Te_n,f>=<e_n,T^*f>$ is very Common and we saw it in the course alot. But when I look at it now it looks like $<Te_n,f>=<e_n,T^*f>=f(Te_n)$ since $T^*:H^*\rightarrow H^*$. But $f\in H$ not a function. What I'm I missing?